# How to register a button press to number I want, even though player pressed it more?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity game where a character punches. I have 3 punch animations and when I press F, punch 1 animation plays, and counter goes up. Then next time player pressed F, punch 2 animation plays and counter goes up. Again, next time player pressed F, punch 3 animation plays and counter goes back to 0. However, each animation has different play time and when punch 1 plays, player can quickly press F button and counter will go up to 3 and then to 0 and only 1 or 2 animations will play.

I've tried using coroutines, counter goes up by that amount of time, but the animation isn't playing.
Coroutine code:

```
    {
        isPunching = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F);
        if(isPunching == true && punchCounter == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine("waitTime");
        }
        else if (isPunching == true && punchCounter == 1)
        {
            punchCounter = 2;
        }
        else if (isPunching == true && punchCounter == 2)
        {
            punchCounter = 3;
        }
        else if (punchCounter == 3)
        {
            punchCounter = 0;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator waitTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        punchCounter = 1;
    }
```

Original code:

```
    {
        isPunching = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F);
        if(isPunching == true && punchCounter == 0)
        {
            punchCounter = 1;
        }
        else if (isPunching == true && punchCounter == 1)
        {
            punchCounter = 2;
        }
        else if (isPunching == true && punchCounter == 2)
        {
            punchCounter = 3;
        }
        else if (punchCounter == 3)
        {
            punchCounter = 0;
        }
    }
```

I want to make a waiting time for when F is pressed, that animation will play and then counter will go to 2, even though player pressed the button more than 1. There is a chance player will be bashing buttons.

Comment: You need to ignore the input entirely when the animation is playing. Look into animation events.

Comment: Of topic, but it's simpler and more legible to just write `if(isPunching && punchCounter == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out animation event here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html

and Youtube tutorial from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IuvXTnQS4U

Place the event to the animation call method when you want player to be able to punch again.

```
public bool isAnimating;

public void AnimationEvent()
{
     isAnimating = false;
}

void Update()
{
    isPunching = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F);

    if(isAnimating == false && isPunching && punchCounter == 0)
    {
        punchCounter = 1;
        isAnimating = true;
    }
    else if (isAnimating == false  && isPunching && punchCounter == 1)
    {
        punchCounter = 2;
        isAnimating = true;
    }
    else if (isAnimating == false  && isPunching && punchCounter == 2)
    {
        punchCounter = 3;
        isAnimating = true;
    }
    else if (punchCounter == 3)
    {
        punchCounter = 0;
    }
}
```